# NestedScrollView Overlapping toolbar (They are inside of a Fragment Layout)

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments

**I'm trying to add `CoordinatorLayout`including a `Toolbar` inside of a Fragment layout. But the problem is that the contents of the `NestedScrollView` Overlapping to the `Toolbar`, as you see in image below :**

[image]

> I tried to add a `RelativeLayout` parent and use
>   `android:layout_below="@+id/coordinatorlayout"` for the
>   `NestedScrollView`,but this make the content of `NestedScrollView` not
>   showing up.

**Fragment layout Code :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorlayout"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar2"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:titleTextColor="#FFFFFF">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView      
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/search_icon"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_height="24dp"
                        android:layout_width="24dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp" />

                    <EditText
                        android:hint="Search"
                        android:id="@+id/searchEditText"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
                </RelativeLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                android:text="hello"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: try to put your nestedscrollview into coordinatorlayout

Comment: @oguzhand i tried it before and get same result above : (

Comment: did you tried to remove relativelayout and let coordinatorlayout as parent, then put your nestedscrollview inside coordinatorlayout?

Comment: @KayoLima i try it now, and same result. even when i remove NestedScrollView the button is still overlapping to the toolbar !!

Comment: try put height to wrap and below property into the NestedScrollView properties android:layout_below="@+id/coordinatorlayout"

Comment: @tompadre yes thank you ♥♥

Comment: Glad it helped. :)  Just mark my comment as helpful. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** Use `CoordinatorLayout` as `root` layout.

**2.** Add `AppBarLayout` and `NestedScrollView` inside `CoordinatorLayout`.

**3.** Put `Toolbar` inside `AppBarLayout`.

**Here is the working code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar2"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:titleTextColor="#FFFFFF">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content">

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/search_icon"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_height="24dp"
                            android:layout_width="24dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp" />

                        <EditText
                            android:hint="Search"
                            android:id="@+id/searchEditText"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
                    </RelativeLayout>
                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                    android:text="hello"/>

            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Hope this will help~

Comment: thanks my friend ♥ my problem is already solved. your answer is right too but has a little problem as you see the NestedScrollView has `match_parent` height so the button will overlap the toolbar agian on scroll :)

Comment: Button will not overlap because NestedScrollView has app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" and AppBarLayout used above NestedScrollView. So their is no overlapping issue. You can check this by using my code.

Comment: I have tested in my device its working properly. Just use my code and also update button  height to 600dp to make the content scroll.

Comment: You can use attribute android:elevation="8dp" to your Toolbar or AppBarLayout for elevation. BTW, using my code its showing elevation on my device.

Answer (score 1):

**Thanks to @tompadre**

 The one and only solution was that i have to change the `width="match_parent"` of both `CoordinatorLayout` and `NestedScrollView` to `wrap_content` and the add this code below to `NestedScrollView` :

```
android:layout_below="@+id/coordinatorlayout"
```

a really simple problem wasted my time for an hour :/

Comment: may i know, why you mark accepted to your answer? Previously you had accepted my answer and now you changed it. What's wrong with my answer?